# JMS - Distributed Transaction

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, jms, distributed-transactions

In case we want a JMS session to participate in transaction, we create a JMS session with session parameter to true.

But, where does I mentioned JMS that it the session being participated in transaction is local transaction or global transaction?

In other words, do I have control to make JMS participate in local or global transaction or it is Application Container who will decide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the connection factory you use.

The specification for JMS specifies two different types of connection factories with each type containing three interfaces.

> XAConnectionFactory, XAQueueConnectionFactory and
>   XATopicConnectionFactory

for the XA connection factories and

> ConnectionFactory, QueueConnectionFactory and TopicConnectionFactory

for the non-XA connection factories. If you use XA**** , then your JMS session will participate in a global transaction. Of course, this part is abstracted away from your code since one typically configures the connection factories via the provider-specific interfaces and then looks them up through JNDI.

Here is a [link](http://weblogic.sys-con.com/node/44439) that talks about global transactions for JMS in WebLogic.